# Indexing elements in rows of multidimensional array at indexes given by another array

Tags: arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have a question which should have a simple solution but I have not found a nice way to deal with it with the standard methods of indexing of numpy.

Suppose I have an array $A$ with a general shape (a1,a2,...,an, b). Then I have a second array of indexes I of shape (a1,a2,..., an) whose entries are integer number in 0,..., b-1. What I would like to do is to use I as the indexes at which A is computed, returning an array F of shape (a1,a2,...,an) such that

`F[i1,i2,..., in] = A[i1,i2,..., in, I[i1,i2,..., in]]`

For n = 2, a simple solution is the following

`F = A[np.arange(n), I]`

where `n = A.shape[0]`. But for the general case I have not found a general and simple solution. What would you suggest?

Comment: Have you tried to extend the n=2 case to n=3?  That should give ideas of how to generalize beyond that.  `A[np.arange(n),I]` is just a case of `advanced indexing`, where the two arrays, `np.arange(n)` and `I` broadcast against each other to specify the return elements.  In principal you do the same with `A[K,J,I]`, with all the arrays broadcasting.  `np.ix_` can be used to construct the more general `K`,`J`, etc.

Comment: In newer versions there's a `np.take_along_axis` function that can simplify this type of indexing.  But It's still a good idea to understand how to generalize the 2d case.

Answer (score 0):

A way to generalise the `n=2` case is to employ the general relation holding for the advanced indexing

```
result[i_1, ..., i_M] == x[ind_1[i_1, ..., i_M], ind_2[i_1, ..., i_M],
                           ..., ind_N[i_1, ..., i_M]]
```

as given in [Indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html) by numpy.
To use this for `n=3` for instance, we need

```
a0,a1,a2 = A.shape
F = A[np.reshape(np.arange(a0), (a0,1)), np.reshape(np.arange(a1), (1, a1)), I]
```

For a general `n` this can be written as follows

```
sha = A.shape[:-1]
indones = [-1] + [1]*(len(sha)-1)
ind = [np.reshape(np.arange(s), np.roll(indones, i)) for i,s in enumerate(sha)]

F = A[tuple(ind + [I])]
```

Not sure if this is the most efficient (and most pythonic) way, but it works.